# Gsub in-place not working

Tags: ruby, string, nokogiri

I have this code:

```
Firm.all.each do |firm|
    url = firm.site
    doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open(url))
    data = doc.css("##{firm.menu_id} a")
    data.each do |e|
      e.text.strip!
      e.text.gsub!(/[\n\t]*/,'')
      puts e.text
    end
end
```

The strings are being displayed in the same format as the input (that means, the `gsub!` method is not affecting the string). I think that `e.text` can be immutable, but I'd like to ensure that.

Comment: What if you put this e.text to a string variable and then gsub! it?

Comment: If `e.text` was `frozen` (eg. `immutable`), a `RuntimeError` would be raised.

Comment: @rockskull I tried what you say and it works.
I changed the lines for `text = e.text.strip` and `text.gsub!(/[\n\t]*/,'')` and it worked. But with `e.text`, the in-place methods are not working. BTW, the RuntimeError is not being displayed, so considering what @PeteyT says `e.text` is mutable.

Comment: There are way too many external dependencies in this code to be able to adequately debug it. How are we supposed to debug your code if we cannot even run it? Please provide a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Well, the problem wasn't in the gsub! method itself. As August said, is because of the usage of Nokogiri. Next time I will provide a minimal example. Thanks for your advice Jorg.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `text` method returns a new String each time, which can be seen using `object_id`:

```
e = Nokogiri::XML('<a>text</a>')

e.text.object_id == e.text.object_id # => false
```

If you want to modify the node's text, set the content:

```
e.at_css('a').content = "foo"
e.text # => "foo"
```

Comment: @cizambra why don't you also upvote the answer if you found it helpful?

Comment: I tried but it seems I don't have enough reputation to do that (Vote Up requires 15 reputation).

Comment: Then go through the Stack Overflow tutorials and you'll have plenty of reputation to actually use the site's features. That *IS* why they have the tutorials and award points. :-)